# Send all attachments in a record upon Submitting

Tags: email, attachment, approval-process

Is it possible to somehow send an email which will contain all of the attachments which are in a record when a user kicks off the Approval Process ? I would like to have an Approver of a process receive all of the information of a record, including the attachments, so he can simply read the attachments from the email and eventually just approve the request from the email.

Can this be done ?

Anybody got any ideas ?

Comment: Are you planning to use standard approval process to do this or Apex or process builder ?

Comment: I had hoped to use either Approval Process and/or Process Builder. I was hoping I could accomplish it without Apex. Thank you.